# Binary vs Ternary relationship in databases

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am having a really hard time trying to understand why whenever possible a binary relationship is better choice than a ternary relationship. I'm at a beginner level in databases and I would really appreciate it if you could explain it with a simple example

Comment: They model different things and therefore neither is "better" in absolute terms. Use one or the other as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use what is appropriate to model the situation. I see no reason to avoid ternary relationships.

An example of a binary relationship:

Suppliers supply products. Each supplier can supply multiple products. Different suppliers can supply the same product.

[image: Binary relationship]

An example of a ternary relationship:

Suppliers distribute products in various regions. Any supplier can distribute any product in any region.

[image: Ternary relationship]

Comment: Can you please give an example where a binary is used and where ternary is used

Comment: Done - hope that helps.